# Game centre user turn notification banner is not display in background mode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, notifications, game-center, ios9.2

I am developing an app in which I have implemented a small turn based game using game centre. I have facing a problem and problem is when I have start the game and invite a friend then the notification banner with appropriate message is display on friend device but when he play the game and give turn to me and when my app is in background mode then only the badge is display but notification banner is not display but if I have remove the app from background then notification banner appears correctly. This process is running correctly with iOS 7 & 8 but not with iOS 9. Please suggest me any idea to solve this.
    Thanks in advance!